# Incorrect syntax near keyword 'd1'

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

The SQL query works in SQL Server Management Studio. But, in Visual studio it gives an error

> Incorrect syntax near D1

Code:

```
private void GetDataByID(string _id)
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
         string sqlCommand = "SELECT  d1.*, d2.* FROM KFM.dbo.ToolBoxDocContent as d1, KFM.dbo.ToolBoxDocument as d2" +
               "where d1.DocumentId = d2.DocumentId and = d2.DocumentId =" + _id;

         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCommand, connection);
         SqlDataReader MyReader;

         try
         {
                connection.Open();
                MyReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (MyReader.Read())
                {
                    string sDueWeek = MyReader["DueWeek"].ToString();
                    string sTitle = MyReader["DocumentTitle"].ToString();
                    //string sEnglishBodyContent = MyReader["DocumentBody"].ToString();
                    //string sFrenchBodyContent = MyReader["DocumentBody"].ToString();
                    txb_Week.Text = sDueWeek;
                    txb_Title.Text = sTitle;
                }
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
                Response.Write(ex.Message);
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Comment: have a look at my answer. hope it will help you to solve your problem.

Comment: Worse habit to kick: using string concatenation to include user input in the sql statement. That will leave you vulnerable to an sql injection attack.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One thing I have noticed in your query is that

1. space is not provided properly before two joins using '+'. Use space before `where`
2. incorrect syntax at `where` clause. remove extra **'='** after **`and`** at `and = d2.DocumentId = " + _id`

Your final query will look like as mentioned below:

```
string sqlCommand = "SELECT  d1.*, d2.* FROM KFM.dbo.ToolBoxDocContent as d1, KFM.dbo.ToolBoxDocument as d2" +
                   " where d1.DocumentId = d2.DocumentId and d2.DocumentId =" + _id;
```

**Update:**

```
string sqlCommand = "SELECT  d1.*, d2.* FROM KFM.dbo.ToolBoxDocContent as d1, KFM.dbo.ToolBoxDocument as d2" +
                   " where d1.DocumentId = d2.DocumentId and d2.DocumentId = '" + _id + "'";
```

Comment: Request ID = a610fa71-fbb6-4cea-a950-b8d4bd83f47f
Incorrect syntax near 'cea'.

Comment: I've changed it and now it sais: Incorrect syntax near 'cea', 'cea' is a part of ID. Or if I chose deferent record ; Invalid column name 'b47a851b'. Invalid column name 'ccac'. Invalid column name 'aca1'. Invalid column name 'a2adab1643ca'. So, depends on a record I click it gives me deferent message

Comment: have a look at my updated answer. hope you will solve your problem.

Comment: Down voter : Don't down vote the answer without providing strong reason.

Answer (score 1):

Change the query as shown below

```
 "SELECT  d1.*, d2.* FROM KFM.dbo.ToolBoxDocContent as d1, KFM.dbo.ToolBoxDocument as d2
           where d1.DocumentId = d2.DocumentId and  d2.DocumentId ='" + _id + "'";
```

Answer (score 1):

In your query, you also have  entered =  sign after and.

Try this code

```
string sqlCommand = "SELECT d1.*, d2.* FROM KFM.dbo.ToolBoxDocContent d1 inner join KFM.dbo.ToolBoxDocument as d2 on d1.DocumentId = d2.DocumentId " + " where d2.DocumentId = " + _id;
```

Also it's better to write store procedure instead and call from your c# code.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void GetDataByID(string _id)
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    string sqlCommand = "SELECT  d1.*, d2.* "
                 + " FROM KFM.dbo.ToolBoxDocContent as d1"
                 + " INNER JOIN KFM.dbo.ToolBoxDocument as d2 ON d1.DocumentId = d2.DocumentId" 
                 + " WHERE d2.DocumentId = @ID";    

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCommand, connection))
    {
        cmd.Parameter.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(_id);
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader MyReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()_
            {
                while (MyReader.Read())
                {
                    string sDueWeek = MyReader["DueWeek"].ToString();
                    string sTitle = MyReader["DocumentTitle"].ToString();
                    //string sEnglishBodyContent = MyReader["DocumentBody"].ToString();
                    //string sFrenchBodyContent = MyReader["DocumentBody"].ToString();
                    txb_Week.Text = sDueWeek;
                    txb_Title.Text = sTitle;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```